# Get props of Child Element of Component

Tags: react-native

```
<TouchableOpacity style= {myStyle.touchableStyle}  >
  <CardSection style={myStyle.cardStyle} onPress= {this.actionPressed} >
      <Icon name={this.props.iconFirst} size={30} color="#000" />
  </CardSection>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This is my Touchable Opacity and I have used onPress on CardSection which is my self defined component. Now, I want to print the name of Icon whenever I press CardSection. The iconName is passed as iconFirst props from parent component. Is there any way, I can get access to Icon name without using onPress on Icon?